# Redirect URL alternatives with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am able to redirect URL to another URL with htaccess by using the following directive:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example$
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/example [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/example [L,R=301]
```

But I want to make this with a single directive in htaccess and this directive should cover all alternatives;

```
http://mydomain.com/example -> http://mydomain.com/pages/example
http://mydomain.com/example/ -> http://mydomain.com/pages/example
http://mydomain.com/example/test -> http://mydomain.com/pages/example/test
```

How can I do this with a single .htaccess? Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^example(/(test)?)?$ /pages/example$1 [L,R=301]
```